# Sending a message from MainController to Delegate - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

I'm sending an interactive local notification with one button.
The local notification text is taken from an array in **MainViewController**.
Yet i have to set it's title in the **AppDelegate**...
Once this button is pressed - the app responds and sends me another local notification with different text and a different button title.
The issue is - the text for the button is placed in a `second array` in the **MainViewController**. 
How would you guys handle such a thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would make this array a public variable in `MainViewController`. Also, I would have a reference to `MainViewController` in `AppDelegate`. Then simply refer to `MainViewController` instance in `AppDelegate` and get that array.

Alternatively, you can create a similar array variable in `AppDelegate`. When `MainViewController` is loaded and the title array is computed, access `AppDelegate` and the title array on `AppDelegate`. Now, directly access this title array like a local variable.

As a side note, if this is a static array, why don't you simply set it in `AppDelegate`?